# Why is my Python code reading things in an if else statement that it's not supposed to?

Tags: python, windows, if-statement

For some reason, my code executes things that aren't supposed to be run, stuff in if ... else statements.

```
if platform == "win32":
  if str(platform.release()) == "10" or str(platform.release()) == "11":
    print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}Welcome to {bcolors.BOLD}B Kernel{bcolors.ENDC}")
  else:
    print("Welcome to B Kernel.")
else:
  print(f"{bcolors.WARNING}Welcome to {bcolors.BOLD}B Kernel{bcolors.ENDC}")

return True
```

It runs the third line of that snippet, even if I use it on Windows 7. It's supposed to run the 5th line, but no.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YRsl.png)

I changed the first line from 'Windows' to 'win32' suspecting the error came from the 7th line, but it came from the third, and the same error resulted.

Comment: What even is `platform` that you can compare it to a string directly but also call `release()` on it?

Comment: How about you print the values of the expressions you're checking to see if they're what you expect?

Comment: `platform` gets the OS type (Windows, macOS, Linux) While 'release' is the OS Version (XP, 7, 10, 11)

Comment: Yeah, but you haven't called anything on it, you're just comparing the module to a string

Comment: There's no possible way the 3rd line is executing.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you mean: `if platform.platform == "win32"`?

Comment: @khelwood It does work, it says 'linux'. (I'm using VSCode on Github)

Comment: @quamrana No, it errors out.

Comment: Did you mean: `if platform.platform() == "win32"`?

Comment: The entire premise of the post and question is incorrect. There are no errors, you just run the bottom most `print` because your first if is `false`. And if the first if was `true` *then* you would actually get an error because line 2 most likely makes no sense.

Comment: "It does work, it says 'linux'" - Wait, it says Linux? Then why are you expecting it to go down the `if platform == "win32":` branch?

Answer (score 1):

It's not running the 3rd line. It's running the 7th, which is identical to the 3rd. `platform` is not equal to `"win32"`; most likely, `platform` is the [`platform` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html), which is not equal to a string.

If `platform` *was* `"win32"`, then you would get an exception when you tried to call `platform.release()`.

Comment: I guess you *could* have an implementation behind `platform` with a weird `__eq__` implementation, which is why I asked for clarification what `platform` is supposed to be, couldn't you? Probably you are right with the guess of the module...

Comment: I added a command, which DOES print platform.release to the screen

Comment: @Erik44b now you say `platform.release` which is once again something ENTIRELY different than both `platform` and `platform.release()`. Syntax and being consistent and specific really matters on SO and in programming in general. You should maybe delete your code and start over from scratch, add `print` statements for every variable you ever use before having them in a `if`, etc.